# Is there any sdk for developing ubuntu desktop application

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I want to develop an application for my Ubuntu desktop but i am not able to find anything like android studio to develop my own application.
Please do suggest me how i can make a desktop application on my own desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two SDKs you can use (in a language you prefer - eg. C, C++, python ...)

You have to decide which widget kits you want to use: GTK3 (very close to linux) or QT5 (which can be used on other OS as well).
The languages I've mentioned support both. You need the right imports.
A simple example for a very small python "app" is [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/MediaInfoGui)
That example shows you how to build a GTK3 or QT5 app using some libraries that linux/Ubuntu offers.